# wordpress posts page canonical

Tags: wordpress, seo, canonical-link, yoast

Hi at the moment I have an issue with the canonicals of the posts page.

each post page got a wrong canonical

for example I haf this page:

http://www.blog.de/page/2

canonical is: http://www.blog.de/page/2
canonical should be: http://www.blog.de/

how can I change this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using some plugin, which generates a canonical URL. Most probably Yoast SEO plugin. If Yoast SEO plugin, you can use this filter:

```
add_filter('wpseo_canonical' , 'change_canonical', 10,1):

function change_canonical($url){
   if(is_home()) { // Checking if Blog listing page
     $url = 'http://www.blog.de/'; 
    } else if(is_page('other')) { // you can check any page, single or any condition you want
      $url = 'http://www.blog.de/other-page'
    }
  return $url;
}
```

Let me know if it works or you are using different plugin. Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks. thats close to that what I need. but this changes all canonicals. I only want to change the canonicals of the blog post listing page. The posts it selfe should have their own canonical.

Comment: I just updated. You see if it helps. You can add any condition like `is_page`, `is_single` and/or `is_singular()`. Just don't forget to write `return $url` outside any condition. So, if the condition doesn't match it will return default.